# how to ignore array ID for validating array in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

That I want to make validation on an array value, and this is my code:

I have a function that can make a query to another table using hasMany but I want to validate that query must be unique. I tried to use this `"required|unique:deed_legalization_numbers, number"` and that's work but when I tried to update/edit some field, it will return **already taken**.

Then i tried to make ignoring ID in unique:

```
"required|unique:deed_legalization_numbers, number, [$request->input('deed_legalization_numbers')]"
```

it will return array to string conversion, because not support array

Then I tried this code:

```
$deed_legalization_numbers = $request->input('deed_legalization_numbers.*.number');
$deed_legalization_id = $request->input('deed_legalization_numbers.*.id');


$rules = [
    'deed_legalization_numbers.*.number' => //'required|unique:deed_legalization_numbers,number,deed_legalization_numbers.*.id',
    [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('deed_legalization_numbers')->where(function ($query) use ($deed_legalization_numbers, $deed_legalization_id) {
            return $query->whereIn('number', $deed_legalization_numbers);
        })->ignore($deed_legalization_id[0]) // The problem in this line
    ],
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

I want to ignore that deed_legalization_numbers ID from checking, if i changed  variable `$deed_legalization_id[0]` to `$deed_legalization_id`
it will return error :

Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Unique::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: addslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file ..path\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationRuleParser.php on line 233

## 0 {main}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching so many threads, then I found the solution to my problem

So, I just change this

```
$deed_legalization_id = $request->input('deed_legalization_numbers.*.id');

$rules = [
    'deed_legalization_numbers.*.number' => //'required|unique:deed_legalization_numbers,number',
    [
        'required',
        'distinct',
        Rule::unique('deed_legalization_numbers', 'number')->where(function ($query) use ($deed_legalization_id) {
            $query->whereNotIn('id', $deed_legalization_id);
            return $query;
        })
    ],
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $message);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

And everything is just fine, no more duplicate column_number and must be unique

Answer (score 1):

Your self-answer was helpful. Not sure if it was there 2 years ago, but there is [an undocumented helper method called `whereNotIn()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/DatabaseRule.php#L165) that allows you to skip the callback stuff. So I would do this for your case:

```php
$deed_legalization_id = $request->input('deed_legalization_numbers.*.id');

$rules = [
    'deed_legalization_numbers.*.number' => [
        'required',
        'distinct',
        Rule::unique('deed_legalization_numbers', 'number')
            ->whereNotIn('id', $deed_legalization_id),
    ],
];
```

This results in the same database query:

```sql
select count(*) as aggregate from `deed_legalization_numbers` where `number` = ? and (`id` not in (?));
```